# Win10 1803 (KB4462919) prompts for reboot. Can I disable? Will it delete my files/crash?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, data-loss-prevention

Given the recent news about Windows Update 1809, I am concerned about allowing my PC to reboot.

It is Win10 x64, and the prompt is for 2018-10 Cumulaitve Update 1803 for x64 (KB4462919).

A few things about my PC:

1. It has an SSD (c:\ 11/237gb free, boot, windows volume) and HDD (d:\ 1.59/1.81 tb free, data volume)
2. There are several accounts, for mine, I redirected the Documents/Pictures/Desktop folders to be in the d:\ drive (d:\users\me\documents etc.), however there are still files that remain in c:\users\me..

Given the recent snafus and that if I could avoid it, I don't want to backup GB's and GB's of data for every update, is there a beyond usual danger of Windows 10 deleting my files or becoming stuck in an update loop due to only 11GB available on the C:\ drive?

Answer (score 0):

> It is Win10 x64, and the prompt is for 2018-10 Cumulative Update 1803 for x64 (KB4462919).

`KB4462919` isn't the 1809 feature update.  Even if it was, Microsoft is no longer pushing, the applicable build at this time.  With that said you really should perform appropriate backups. Any update could, in theory, cause a problem.

> Given the recent snafus and that if I could avoid it, I don't want to backup GB's and GB's of data for every update.

You should obviously have a backup of any files you cannot afford to lose.

> is there a beyond usual danger of Windows 10 deleting my files or becoming stuck in an update loop due to only 11GB available on the C:\ drive?

If you are worried and you are running Windows 10 Professional just defer quality updates.  You can also pause updates, allowing you 35 days, to perform any appropriate backup you need.  **Seriously, if you had proper backups, you wouldn't worry about installing a critical security update.**

If the update is already pending to be installed, then it's you won't be able to defer this particular update, so you should go ahead and just install it.

[image]

Comment: Worth pointing out that Windows 10 has received hundreds of cumulative updates if you include all the patches that the Insider Preview branch receives over the course of nearly 4 years.  A single build, within the RS5 branch, had the data loss issue you describe.  Microsoft indicated it was only applicable to 1% of 1% of Windows 10 users.  So while `KB4462919` could have a problem, the benefits of having it installed, should also be considered.  *Backups are handy, for any possible issues, that surround patching any operating system that might surface*

Comment: Hi Ramhound, thanks for your answer to my question.1% of 1% is still too much of a risk for me to take, however I don't think I ever specifically signed up for the Insider program and the version I have is "Windows 10 Home" and mine doesn't have the option below "pause updates" in your screenshot. At this point of prompting a reboot, it doesn't look possible to disable it.

Comment: It would’ve be possible even if you had Professional if the update was already installed and you are being prompted for a reboot.  The deferment was for next time.

Comment: At this point, is there still a 1% of 1% (0.01%) chance of my account folders being wiped if I were to follow the prompt and reboot?

Comment: @user3645994 I cannot predict the future.  The patch in question, is not linked, to any problem even remotely related to that of the problems within the pulled initial 1809 release.

Comment: Hi again. The screen above doesn't appear to be available on my installation (win 10 home) and apparently I am prompted for yet another reboot to update (2018-11 v1803 KB4467702) that they are now trying. In update settings on my version of windows, there are no options to pause or select which channel.

Comment: You should be able to chnage the channel regardless of the edition (Windows 10 Professional, Windows 10 Home, etc.) but deferring updates is limited to Windows 10 Professional, Windows 10 Enterprise, and Windows 10 Education.  KB4667702 is a normal cumulative update, that will happen, likely every week or two.  KB4462919 was released more then a month ago, while KB4467702, was released today and it should be installed.  My answer clearly indicates it applies to Windows 10 Professional.